# Solving $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac1x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac1{x^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}=-a$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac1x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac1{x^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}=-a$$
>   $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\big|_{x=0}=0, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\big|_{x=b}=l^2$$
>   ($l\in\Bbb R$).

I am trying to solve this linear differential equation but I am struggling to come up with a correct technique to solve this. Separation of variables is not effective due to the $-a$ term on the RHS.

I haven't tried Fourier transforms yet, because I feel like there may be an easier way to do this.

There is also the option of series solutions, but of course a closed form solution (if available) would be preferable.

I have tried Wolfram Alpha since it could give an indication of what the solution should look like, but it didn't solve the equation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for a particular solution of the complete equation. It is easy to find one depending only on $x$. This gives an ODE of Euler type, and is easy to see that there is a particular solution of the form $f_p(x,t)=A\,x^2$ for a certain constant $A$. Then let $f=u+f_p$, and obtain a the same equation for $u$ with the right-hand side equal to $0$.

Comment: Having worked through this just now, are both of these boundary conditions possible together? Or does applying one determine what $l^2$ is? I ask this because we have a second order equation with two boundary conditions on the derivative of $x$, so (focusing on a solution dependent on $x$ only) it is essentially a first order equation for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Looking for $f_p(x)$ as a solution of $f_{xx}+f_x=-a$ satisfying the boundary conditions $f_x(0)=0$, $f_x(b)=l^2$, we get $f_p(x)=C_1+C_2\log x+A\,x^2$. It seems that it is not possible to satisfy both boundary conditions.

Comment: Ok I think I must have formulated the argument wrong earlier to determine where the boundaries were. If it weren't at 0, then it would have been possible so I will try and find out why the boundary isn't at 0. Thanks!

Comment: The particular solution is there to get rid of the inhomogeneous term. It does not have to satisfy the boundary condition. The resulting difference in boundary condition is left to for the homogenous part $u$ of the solution to resolve. Until one examines the solution of $u$, he can not draw conclusions regarding the feaibility of the boundary condition.